# Error en conteo de votos en eleccion

Tags: soporte, estado-por-diseño, votos, elecciones, página-de-elecciones

He estado revisando el [sitio de elección](https://es.stackoverflow.com/election), he notado que *al igual que cualquier publicación, se pueden observar los votos positivos y negativos de los diferentes candidatos*, obviamente, teniendo ya dicho privilegio.

Cuando he visto la [publicación de Joel Ibaceta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/election/1#post-87558), he notado lo siguiente:

Esta es la **puntuación** que aparece en la publicación.

[image: Puntuación normal]

Mas, al hacer clic y mirar la **diferencia de votos**.

[image: Puntuación avanzada]

Si no me falla la matemática `17 - 21 = -4`, por lo tanto mi pregunta es:

**¿Por qué, si habiendo una diferencia de votos positivos versus negativos, la diferencia no concuerda con el valor?**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Se decidió en el sitio en inglés allá por el 2011 o 2012 que era innecesario y cruel mostrar votos negativos más allá de -1, puesto que el objetivo es ver quienes son los mejores candidatos no los peores (según la opinion de los votantes)

En esta [respuesta a Election primary vote count is no lower than -1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135577/137182) se explica un poco.

> There was talk during the SO election that massively negative scores was unnecessarily demoralizing; the point of the primary is to find the 10 best candidates, not to say "this person is ridiculously awful and deserves hundreds of downvotes"

Traducción:

> Durante las elecciones de SO se habló de que las puntuaciones masivas negativas eran innecesariamente desmoralizadoras. El punto de las primarias es encontrar los 10 mejores candidatos, no decir "esta persona es ridículamente horrible y merece cientos de votos negativos"

Comment: Oh! No tenia idea al respecto, muchas gracias por la aclaracion

Answer (score 4):

Si un usuario tiene más votos negativos que positivos, para que no se sienta mal, lo muestra en cero. Además, el número es mostrado diferente para cada usuario que lo vota.

Hay varios escenarios. Si luego de hacer la resta entre los positivos y negativos (para verlo hay que tener un privilegio), el resultado es:

- **0** y voto positivo, queda con **1** punto.
- **0** y no voto, queda en **0**.
- **0** y voto en contra, tiene **-1**.
- **1** y voto en contra, tiene **0**.
- **-1** y voto positivo, tiene **0**.
- **-1 o menos** y no voto, tiene **0**.
- **-1 o menos** y voto en contra, tiene **-1**.
- **menor a -1** y voto positivo, tiene **1**.